# Alphanumeric Filename Natural Sorting in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am working in content management of an E-Book publication database. Text contents are stored in **eb_contents** (VARCHAR) TABLE and accessed by **page_name** (VARCHAR). My page_name value like below -

```
EBook-00GUKP1142-10.jpg
EBook-00GUKP1142-11.jpg
EBook-00GUKP1142-12.jpg
EBook-00GUKP1142-7.jpg
EBook-02GUKP1375-1.jpg
EBook-02GUKP1375-4.jpg
EBook-02GUKP1375-5.jpg
EBook-02GUKP1375-52.jpg
EBook-02GUKP1375-53.jpg
EBook-02GUKP1375-56.jpg
EBook-02GUKP1375-57.jpg
EBook-02GUKP1375-6.jpg
EBook-04GUKP2577-17.jpg
EBook-04GUKP2577-26.jpg
EBook-04GUKP2577-27.jpg
EBook-04GUKP2577-28.jpg
EBook-04GUKP2577-68.jpg
EBook-04GUKP2577-69.jpg
EBook-05GUKP1661-1.jpg
```

I have tried implementing different sorting methods like below. But unable to get the result as expected. Any help is most welcome.

```
SELECT * FROM `eb_contents` ORDER BY Cast(page_name as Unsigned), page_name;
```

Comment: I can sort this every which way. What is the result **you** expect?

Comment: seems like it's already sorted, can you share what you really expect as output?

Comment: I want natural sorting like -

EBook-00GUKP1142-7.jpg

EBook-00GUKP1142-10.jpg

EBook-00GUKP1142-11.jpg

EBook-00GUKP1142-12.jpg

Comment: ```...
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(page_name, '-', 2), 0 + SUBSTRING_INDEX(page_name, '-', -1)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your input only
Try This

```
SELECT *
FROM `eb_contents`
ORDER BY 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(page_name, '-', 1),
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(page_name, '-', -2), '-', 1) AS UNSIGNED),
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(page_name, '-', -1) AS UNSIGNED),
  page_name;
```

**output**

| page_name |
| --- |
| EBook-00GUKP1142-7.jpg |
| EBook-00GUKP1142-10.jpg |
| EBook-00GUKP1142-11.jpg |
| EBook-00GUKP1142-12.jpg |
| EBook-02GUKP1375-1.jpg |
| EBook-02GUKP1375-4.jpg |
| EBook-02GUKP1375-5.jpg |
| EBook-02GUKP1375-6.jpg |
| EBook-02GUKP1375-52.jpg |
| EBook-02GUKP1375-53.jpg |
| EBook-02GUKP1375-56.jpg |
| EBook-02GUKP1375-57.jpg |
| EBook-04GUKP2577-17.jpg |
| EBook-04GUKP2577-26.jpg |
| EBook-04GUKP2577-27.jpg |
| EBook-04GUKP2577-28.jpg |
| EBook-04GUKP2577-68.jpg |
| EBook-04GUKP2577-69.jpg |
| EBook-05GUKP1661-1.jpg |

Comment: EBook-00GUKP1142-7.jpg should be the first result as per natural sort.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert to an numeric type to get the correct ordering.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  pv varchar(255)
);
INSERT INTO test VALUES
('EBook-00GUKP1142-10.jpg'),
('EBook-00GUKP1142-11.jpg'),
('EBook-02GUKP1375-57.jpg'),
('EBook-02GUKP1375-6.jpg'),
('EBook-04GUKP2577-17.jpg'),
('EBook-04GUKP2577-26.jpg'),
('EBook-04GUKP2577-27.jpg'),
('EBook-04GUKP2577-28.jpg'),
('EBook-00GUKP1142-12.jpg'),
('EBook-00GUKP1142-7.jpg'),
('EBook-02GUKP1375-1.jpg'),
('EBook-02GUKP1375-4.jpg'),
('EBook-02GUKP1375-5.jpg'),
('EBook-02GUKP1375-52.jpg'),
('EBook-02GUKP1375-53.jpg'),
('EBook-02GUKP1375-56.jpg'),
('EBook-04GUKP2577-68.jpg'),
('EBook-04GUKP2577-69.jpg'),
('EBook-05GUKP1661-1.jpg')
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT substring(pv,7,2),substring(pv,13,4), convert(substring(pv,18,length(pv)-21),decimal) from test;
```

| substring(pv,7,2) | substring(pv,13,4) | convert(substring(pv,18,length(pv)-21),decimal) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00 | 1142 | 10 |
| 00 | 1142 | 11 |
| 02 | 1375 | 57 |
| 02 | 1375 | 6 |
| 04 | 2577 | 17 |
| 04 | 2577 | 26 |
| 04 | 2577 | 27 |
| 04 | 2577 | 28 |
| 00 | 1142 | 12 |
| 00 | 1142 | 7 |
| 02 | 1375 | 1 |
| 02 | 1375 | 4 |
| 02 | 1375 | 5 |
| 02 | 1375 | 52 |
| 02 | 1375 | 53 |
| 02 | 1375 | 56 |
| 04 | 2577 | 68 |
| 04 | 2577 | 69 |
| 05 | 1661 | 1 |

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT pv from test order by substring(pv,7,2),substring(pv,13,4), convert(substring(pv,18,length(pv)-21),decimal);
```

| pv |
| --- |
| EBook-00GUKP1142-7.jpg |
| EBook-00GUKP1142-10.jpg |
| EBook-00GUKP1142-11.jpg |
| EBook-00GUKP1142-12.jpg |
| EBook-02GUKP1375-1.jpg |
| EBook-02GUKP1375-4.jpg |
| EBook-02GUKP1375-5.jpg |
| EBook-02GUKP1375-6.jpg |
| EBook-02GUKP1375-52.jpg |
| EBook-02GUKP1375-53.jpg |
| EBook-02GUKP1375-56.jpg |
| EBook-02GUKP1375-57.jpg |
| EBook-04GUKP2577-17.jpg |
| EBook-04GUKP2577-26.jpg |
| EBook-04GUKP2577-27.jpg |
| EBook-04GUKP2577-28.jpg |
| EBook-04GUKP2577-68.jpg |
| EBook-04GUKP2577-69.jpg |
| EBook-05GUKP1661-1.jpg |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n3DYgjPtJcjgviihz5VpJS/2)

Comment: JMP, Its working well but the solution is too specific with string value stored in target table. Still I am expecting a generic solution (applicable on any data set). Any further approach towards a generic solution is still waited.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not directly support natural sorting; the best you can do is to break up a known format into parts and sort individually by the parts.

Assuming your format is always:  character string, '-', character string, '-', number, you would sort that like:

```
order by
    substring_index(page_name,'-',1),
    substring_index(substring_index(page_name,'-',2),'-',-1),
    0 + substring_index(page_name,'-',-1)
```